# Force Windows service to use RDP session

Tags: c#, windows-services, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a very specific issue I fail to fix with my application.
I am building up a remote software validation tool (in C#) for a secure software located inside a VDI-type infrastructure built up on Windows Server 2016.

The idea is to USB plug in a smart card with valid a certificate inside a distant computer (using classic Windows 10), access the VDI by connecting via RDP  (using Windows Remote Desktop) and use the validation tool to gain access to the secured application.

Everything works smoothly as long as I am using the application from an executable launched via Visual Studio debug or built up as .exe and launched inside the remote session.

However, I have an obligation to embed the executables as Windows Services, and in such it renders the validation tools unusable. I have found out that it is because in such case the validation software uses the VDI smart card service and not, as I expected, the smart card service from the computer I access the VDI with.

As such, the validation tools seeks for cards on the VDI and not on my access computer.

So, my question is, is there such a way to "hijack" the VDI smart card reader service with the one from my own computer, or is there any way the App can detect the service from my RDP session ?

Thanks

Edit: a simplified C# method code we use to gather the data from the service:

```
        protected void ExtractRawSC()
    {

        //----------------------- TEST SYSCAL

        var proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
        string Command = "certutil -scinfo  > C:\\Users\\Administrateur\\Documents\\output.txt";
        proc1.UseShellExecute = true;

        proc1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";

        proc1.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
        proc1.Verb = "runas";
        proc1.Arguments = "/c " + Command;
        //proc1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(proc1);
        //------------------------
    }
```

Comment: Please show code: how are you accessing this device? And how do you expect to be able to differentiate which smart-card needs to be accessed, given there can be multiple VDI sessions?

Comment: Hello thanks for answering.

Exact code is confidential, but we use a modified version of the cmd command "certutil -scinfo" we perform through a systemcall in C#. I'm adding a simplified version.

Comment: So the output from `certutil` was showing the local (VDI machine's) smart-card *and* the remote one that was redirected over RDP, and now it is only showing the former? Are you waiting until the RDP session is connected in order to run this command? Please [edit] and paste into your post the output from both versions